# What are the correct synonyms for “tangible”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms, word-in-context

> However, the growing popularity of Agile practices begs the question of whether they can be applied to the development of **tangible** physical products and services too?
>
> 1. physical
> 2. measurable
> 3. innovative

Comment: There's a definition of cycle time metrics [here](https://www.extremeuncertainty.com/cycle-time-ead-time/). 'Iterative' comes from [iteration](https://www.lexico.com/definition/iteration). The rest should be easy to find in a [dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tangible).

Comment: It does not help.
for example, viable synonyms is possible and feasible what should I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you  delete six of your seven questions? The links in my comment gave you answers to three of them.

The dictionary I linked to defines **tangible** as *"Perceptible by touch"*. Things you can touch are tangible.
If you can touch something, does that mean it is...

- ...innovative (new)?

No! You can also touch old things.

- ...measurable (able to be measured)?

No! Weight is measurable but you can't touch weight. .

- ...physical? The dictionary gives "**tangible or concrete**" in its definition.

Yes!

In the StackExchange [Tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour) it asks visitors to include details about what they have tried before asking a question. A dictionary is something you should try before asking us what a word means.

Welcome to ELL, by the way!